# Error w/ installing memcached in Docker alpine image

Tags: docker, memcached, telnet

Good day

I want to install Memcached instance in the image I'm working on.

Here is the current code:

```
FROM alpine
USER root

RUN apk update && apk add ca-certificates && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*  \
    && apk --no-cache add memcached busybox-extras && echo "done"\
    && /usr/bin/memcached -v -d \ 
        --user=root \
        --port=11211 \
        --listen=0.0.0.0 \
    && telnet 0.0.0.0 11211        

WORKDIR /root/
COPY --from=builder /go/api/version/version .
CMD ["./version"]
```

And here's the response I get :
`telnet: can't connect to remote host (0.0.0.0): Connection refused`

What is my mistake? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: telnet 127.0.0.1 11211

Comment: @LinPy Oh, yeah, you are right
However, I added the column on purpose in order to debug, because of the same error

Comment: and the `0.0.0.0` is also wrong!

Comment: It looks like you're trying to run _both_ memcached and a Go application; are you sure you don't want a separate [`memcached`](https://hub.docker.com/_/memcached) container?

Comment: @LinPy Why is it? Moreover, 0.0.0.0 came from an article I found while trying to solve the problem. Before it was 127.0.0.1, and error was the same

Comment: @DavidMaze, yeah, it's a solution, and I believe, it's a thing I'm going to do, but I just want to figure out why my current implementation doesn't work